# animate flipping an element horizontally in IE11

Tags: css, animation, transform

I'm trying to animate an element back and forth, with a flip at each end. I'm using a CSS animation with scaleX(-1) at the end. It works fine in everything but IE, where it's shooting the element all the way off the page, then sliding it back into position.

```
@keyframes moveAndFlip {
    48% {   
        transform: translateX(12vh) scaleX(1);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateX(12vh) scaleX(-1); 
    }
    98% {
        transform: translateX(0) scaleX(-1);    
    }   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pq9yqscy/2/

Is this a known issue in IE? Another way to tackle it?

Comment: Have you tried with other units? `px` instead of `vh`... Can be the compatibility with the units

Comment: I was ready to say you're crazy, but changing it to px or % does cause it to work in IE11. Weird!